# jquery, click on current li only

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, onclick, append

Once clicked on it, I'd like to append a ul element to a li element.

My html is the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>list 1</li>
    <li>list 2</li>
    <li>list 3
        <ul>
            <li>list 31</li>
            <li>list 32</li>
            <li>list 33</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>list 4</li>
    <li>list 5</li>
</ul>
```

and my javascript:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function (){
    $(this).append(
        '<ul>'+
            '<li>list a</li>'+
            '<li>list b</li>'+
            '<li>list c</li>'+
        '</ul>'
    )
});
```

My problem is when I click on a li instead of appending the  element to the current li, it appends it to all the li being in the same scope.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/Lneyn80w/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop the event which gets bubbled up the DOM tree,

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('ul').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).append(
      '<ul>' +
      '<li>list a</li>' +
      '<li>list b</li>' +
      '<li>list c</li>' +
      '</ul>'
    );
  });
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lneyn80w/3/)

Comment: thanks, small issue though, in your jsfiddle when clicked on list31 or list32 or list33 the new list is being happened 2 times

Comment: @woshitom Can you check the updated demo? https://jsfiddle.net/Lneyn80w/3/

Comment: working perfectly, many thanks, will validate your answer as soon as possible